# Issue with setting a cookie and modal not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display modal after delay of 2 seconds and also want to do cookie validation before displaying.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("#myModal").modal('show');
    if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the modal is not appearing. If I don't specify an `if` condition then the modal appears. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the cookie hasn't been set already during your testing?

Comment: Yes I tried from a different browser now.  But same result

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? What do you see in the console when you do: `console.log($.cookie('modal_shown'));`

Comment: "$.cookie is not a function" is the output of the console

Comment: There's your problem, you need to add the cookie library to your code, it's not a standard part of jQuery. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Sure i will do that.  Thanks again for the help